# Save multiple image while saving product in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get multiple image upload for my application products, I already tried [this](http://laraveldaily.com/upload-multiple-files-laravel-5-4/) and [this](https://medium.com/@emmanueladegor2/multiple-image-upload-with-remove-link-saving-image-name-to-database-using-dropzone-js-and-ec21b0ab6a01) but no luck :\

Each of them drive me till somewhere and not make tutorial complete, so currently I have no code in my application about multiple upload that's why i didn't share any code in this question.

#### What I need is

Someone help me through this process.

The problem with articles i mentioned above was:

1. They had their own saving method which i don't want that, what i want is when i click on my `products.store` save button photos be save at the same time and not to save photos separately or bring my product validation to photos custom rules. [this article](http://laraveldaily.com/upload-multiple-files-laravel-5-4/)
2. Those tutorials did not provide any method about how to edit or delete photos related to each product which is necessary to be able to remove one or some of uploaded photos or replace them.
3. There was no help about how to get specific photo of product eg. get image 1 $ 2 only. (it's necessary for listing only show 1 or 2 images and total images show in detail page)

I know this seems a lot but i hope someone really can help me with that, it's nothing impossible WordPress,Joomla, Magento etc. all have done it before. I just don't know how!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look whos back :). So you are still not able to attach images to product is that right?

Comment: @usrNotFound LOL

Comment: where are you up to in this journey?

Comment: @usrNotFound definitely i am

Comment: where are you up to?

Comment: @usrNotFound https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159102/discussion-between-usrnotfound-and-mafortis